# Ajax call to get the value selected from a HTML Select Option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

On a dropdown option, I would like to listen in and get the value of the option selected by the user.

Then I would like to pass this value to a PHP variable for use in the later part of the blade view PHP script.

I do not want to reload the page hence from the online look, I found ajax to be the only possible way.

I tried to implement as shown below but hitting a snag as the page loads on submit.

Even better is it possible to have a select option drop down that you get the selected value without submit?

My select option code:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div class="button dropdown">
      <select name="languageSelected" required="required" id="languageselector" onChange='showSelected(this.value)'>
        <option value="">Pick A language</option>
        @foreach($reviewForm_language as $lang)
         <option value="{{$lang->id}}">{{$lang->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
    </div>
    <input id="ajaxSubmit" type="submit" value="Select"/>
</form>
```

My JS code:

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           $.ajaxSetup({
              headers: {
                  'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
              }
          });
           jQuery.ajax({
              url: "{{ url('#') }}",
              method: 'post',
              data: {
                 id: jQuery('#languageSelected').val(),

              },
              success: function(result){
                 jQuery('.alert').show();
                 jQuery('.alert').html(result.success);
              }});
           });
        });
  </script>
```

On reload I can get the value as a GET request as below; however, I do not want to reload the page but for some reasons it does reload.

```
 `<?php
      $langId = request()->get('languageSelected');
  ?>`
```

Anyone?

Comment: You cannot pass a JavaScript value to PHP directly, especially not without reloading the page. PHP is a server-side script. Once the page is loaded, no code will be executed anymore. First of all, you must change your jQuery function to listen to ´submit´ and not ´click´. What do you want to do with the value, or why do you want to hand it over to PHP?

Comment: @Chris I want to display data based on the selected value

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

1. Change type="button" instead of submit

   input id="ajaxSubmit" type="button" value="Select"

2.There is no need for `$.ajaxSetup`. Copy the headers from `$.ajaxSetup` and move above url( inside `jQuery.ajax({` )

3. You are doing other things properly. Now just check in the controller whether you are getting `id` in post parameter using var_dump(`$request->all()`)

Comment: In your controller you will get the id like this : request()->get('id');

Comment: Changed to this `input id="ajaxSubmit" type="button" value="Select"` but seems the form is not being submitted.

Comment: Please check in console. You can see Ajax request in Networks tab if you are using google chrome.

Comment: Getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: showSelected is not defined` on the console

Comment: Seems client side issue in your script. Fix that and it should work.

Comment: One more thing, is the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` correct as I am now getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined`?

Answer (score 0):

instead of type submit change it to button

```
<input id="ajaxSubmit" type="button" value="Select"/>
```

and in php file you shold get id not languageSelected because you have passed id into data in ajax call.

```
 `<?php
  $langId = request()->get('id');
 ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to listen directly to the change event on the select element.

```
<script>    
    jQuery('#languageselector').on('change', function(){      

        jQuery.ajax({
          url: "{{ url('#') }}",
          method: 'post',
          data: {
             id: $(this).val(),
          },
          success: function(result){
             jQuery('.alert').show();
             jQuery('.alert').html(result.success);
          }
        });

    });
</script>
```